# Tableau v 8.0.0 Date format yyyy-mm-dd not changing to mm/dd/yyyy in different servers

Tags: excel, date, publishing, tableau-api

In tableau 8.0.0 i have kept the date format as mm/dd/yyyy . In one Tableau server 1(Live) (8.0.0) i am getting date in the format mm/dd/yyyy but in the other Tableau server 2 (Beta) i am getting the format yyyy-mm-dd . Recently i uninstalled the Beta from version 8.0.0.2  to 8.0.0.1. How to keep the format same in both the servers?

Edited :
The windows region/locale settings in the tableau server and desktop are same. Also the locale setting for tableau desktop is set to USA. But I don't know how to view the locale setting of tableau server. Another thing - for other reports the date format.

Comment: P.S Currently both servers have version 8.0.0.0 now. Actually i uninstalled from 8.0.0.2 to 8.0.0.0.Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Assuming this issue is occurring for the same workbook published to both servers, are the region and locale settings for both Tableau Server machines exactly the same?

Comment: The windows region/locale settings in the tableau server and desktop are same. Also the locale setting for tableau desktop is set to USA. But I don't know how to view the locale setting of tableau server. Another thing - for other reports the date format is found to be same. Only in this report does it appear different. I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Next things to check: has the locale of the workbook been explicitly set "File > Workbook Locale" in Tableau Desktop? Do any correctly displaying workbooks connect to same SQL Server table, using the same fields? If not, then is there anything different about how the date field is defined in that particular table?